# Question - @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AdminController.class) <- why has it broken my application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-web-start

i was getting an issue which I couldn't understand, which was:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method setApplicant in webService.controller.RequestController required a bean of type 'com.service.applicant.Applicant' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.service.applicant.Applicant' in your configuration.
```

I've done some researches but I still couldn't fixed this problem, when I simply removed the @ComponentScan from my Main Application Class and it worked.

I removed:

```
//@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AdminController.class)
```

Everything is fine, but i got curious... Can someone please help me?

Comment: you need to show main and sub packages structure of your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't use @ComponentScan explicity, @SpringBootApplication annotation on your main class has  implementation of @ComponentScan in it(along with @EnableAutoConfiguration). So all the classes marked as @component(or similar annotation like controller, service etc.) get scanned automatically provided they are in the same or sub-package where main class is defined.

Now in your case you added //@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AdminController.class) in your main class. What this did that it only created bean for the class AdminController and ignored all other classes.

Answer (score 0):

you should annotate the class `Applicant` with `@Component` first.
in your main class annotate the object with `@Configuration`, `EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan({"com.service.applicant","your.admin.controller.path"})`.

in the class `RequestController` annotate the property of type `Applicant` with `@Autowire`.